# implementing Local Storage in React useStateValue()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I want to be able to store items selected from my home page in Local Storage, as I'm using `useStateValue()`.

The items display on the Checkout page correctly, however, on refreshing, the Checkout page becomes empty and returns to zero. The code below works fine with normal `useState`. I don't know what I am missing when using `useStateValue()`.

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Checkout.css";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import Subtotal from "./Subtotal";

function Checkout() {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem("my-cart-list");
    if (data) {
      dispatch(JSON.parse(data))
    }
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("my-cart-list", JSON.stringify(basket))
  });
```

Comment: what is `useStateValue`?

Comment: I hope my use-case explanation will help: Component that "holds" && distributes state in my app. My State Provider/useStateValue code is: `import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react"

//Prepares the dataLayer
export const StateContext = createContext()

//This Wrap App
export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children
}) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
)

// Pull information from the datalayer
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext)`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the dependency array, which means that the setItem will be called on every render:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("my-cart-list", JSON.stringify(basket))
});
```

If you want to call setItem when "basket" changes, you should use:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("my-cart-list", JSON.stringify(basket))
}, [basket]);
```

Comment: I've tried this too, still not working.